# How to join two disconnected curves with listplot

Tags: plotting, graphics, numerical-integration, code-review

Actually I want to join the blue and the red curve with another curve (definitely not a straight line, but some smooth curve) to show the transition from blue to red. How can I do this? Please help. My code is the following:

```
Tab1 = {{0.001`, 1.0000019469069152`*^-30}, {0.0031622776601683794`, 
    1.001933480217123`*^-30}, {0.01`, 
    3.164749156731485`*^-30}, {0.03162277660168379`, 
    2.4967200555317485`*^-27}, {0.1`, 
    2.952094736616491`*^-24}, {0.31622776601683794`, 
    3.3063612983907705`*^-21}, {1.`, 
    1.089991755131802`*^-17}, {3.1622776601683795`, 
    1.0690504610554947`*^-15}, {10.`, 
    1.9557537921173713`*^-15}, {31.622776601683793`, 
    1.9558160034327742`*^-15}, {100.`, 
    1.955816003432348`*^-15}, {316.22776601683796`, 
    1.955816003432348`*^-15}, {1000.`, 1.955816003432348`*^-15}};

Tab2 = {{0.001`, -2.342983968269735`*^-8}, {0.0031622776601683794`, \
-2.326145130294078`*^-8}, {0.01`, -2.273706623211469`*^-8}, \
{0.03162277660168379`, -2.1158156575818242`*^-8}, {0.1`, \
-1.690436069797742`*^-8}, {0.31622776601683794`, \
-9.128356981924211`*^-9}, {1.`, 
    1.2004949015357688`*^-8}, {3.1622776601683795`, 
    3.7069167360273327`*^-7}, {10.`, 
    8.23598704162138`*^-7}, {31.622776601683793`, 
    8.286588978525833`*^-7}, {100.`, 
    8.286588951403191`*^-7}, {316.22776601683796`, 
    8.286588951403191`*^-7}, {1000.`, 8.286588951403191`*^-7}};

ListPlot[{Tab1, Tab2}, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
  ImageSize -> 600, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 18], 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Red, Dashed}}, PlotRange -> All] // Quiet
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to fit the beginning of Tab1 to the beginning of Tab2. For this you may try an ArcTan function with a weighted fit  to distribute the errors in the original plot evenly:

```
dat = {{0.001`, 1.0000019469069152`*^-30}, {0.0031622776601683794`, 
    1.001933480217123`*^-30}, {0.01`, 3.164749156731485`*^-30}, {1.`, 
    1.2004949015357688`*^-8}, {3.1622776601683795`, 
    3.7069167360273327`*^-7}, {10.`, 8.23598704162138`*^-7}};
dat1= Log[dat];

fit = NonlinearModelFit[dat1, a  ArcTan[(x - b)/c] + d, {a, b, c, d}, 
  x, Weights -> {1, 1, 1, 100, 100, 100}]

Show[ListPlot[{Tab1, Tab2}, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
  ImageSize -> 600, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 18], 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Red, Dashed}}, PlotRange -> All],
 Plot[Exp@fit[Log[x]],{x, 10^-3, 10}, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"},
   PlotRange -> All, Prolog -> {Red, Point[dat]}]]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

```
Show[ListPlot[{Tab1, Tab2}, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
  ImageSize -> 600, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 18], 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Red, Dashed}}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Tab1", "Tab2"}], 
 Plot[Exp@fit[Log[x]], {x, 10^-3, 10}, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Fit"}, Prolog -> {Red, Point[dat]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Daniel Huber . Actually, I wanted to join the portion of the Tab 1 to the starting of Tab 2 (which is happening around 1 along the X-axis) that shows the transition from blue curve to the red curve and also is it possible to put plotlegends in your code to name all three curves ? I've tried using your code, but didn't get the desired result! I want all three of them in a single box.

Comment: You may extend my fit to include all points to get a single function. To add legends is easy. I added a plot with legends.

Comment: Okay, thanks. But I didn't understand how you chose the weights! I understand there are 6 points in your fit, so you took 6 wights, but why three 1 and three 100 ?

Comment: First three are for the points from Tab1 and last 3 are for the points from Tab2.